# Using Dates in an MVC application

Tags: c#, date, asp.net-mvc-5, date-format, utc

I have coded a MVC 5 internet application and have a question in regards to international dates.

I am wishing to add a create date field to each of my objects when my objects are saved into a SQL database. As this application will be used internationally, what format should I use for the dates and do I need to use a specific UTC?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can either use a single date format and specify that on the view accepting the input or you can go to the trouble of determining where a specific user is and use the date format for that culture.  The second option is more trouble but provides a better user experience.  Which do you want to do?

Comment: There's no "specific UTC".  Presumably you mean "time zone".  If you're only storing dates then time zones are probably irrelevant.  You probably just care about what day something happened for the user entering the data, not whether it was currently the same day elsewhere in the world.  If you were storing time as well and you wanted to represent the exact instant in time that something occurred then time zone would be important so you could show each user the correct time.  For example, let's say that you wanted to report when the next solar eclipse would occur.

Comment: I am basically just wanting to store the date/time when an object is created. Would the database size be considerably larger if I store the date/time, rather than just the date? I am thinking of the situation where the database could have 100,000s of records and I am thinking of the database size.

Comment: Many databases have millions of records with no issue.  Storing the time is going to have no significant impact.  It comes down to what is appropriate to store for the purpose.  If the time is significant then store the time as well as the date.  As for whether to use time zones, are they relevant to your application?  If a user creates a record at a particular time, do you want to show the user what time it was at that moment in their own time zone, in the time zone of the user who created it or in UTC for everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common .NET type is DateTime. A DateTime stores a date and optionally a time. It has a Kind property which determines if the value is one of three: local, UTC, or unspecified.
Another type is called DateTimeOffset. A DateTimeOffset stores a date and time relative to UTC. Additionally, it stores an offset from UTC as TimeSpan.

Console.WriteLine (DateTime.Now);         // 1/28/2014 2:53:50 PM

Console.WriteLine (DateTimeOffset.Now);   // 1/28/2014 2:53:50 PM -08:00

More Information : http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization-date-time.aspx